# Template File not found

Tags: python, html, css, django

So I am trying to open a template from...

[image]

But the template file is not shown as below...

[image]

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "home/index.html")
```

Weird thing is that my webpage still works, and when I delete that function it does not.

Here is some additional Info...

**settings.py**

[image]

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'project_long_page',
    'about',
    'home',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

**home/urls.py**

[image]

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

***Part 2 Question:***

Added...

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))]  # BASE_DIR / 'templates'
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

[image]

**HTML Pages Within App ***(Don't mind errors in .HTML, I'll figure it out!)*****

[image]

**base.html**

[image]

Part 3:
What is interesting is even though it says...
*Unresolved template reference '"main_header.html"'*
the code is still working and posted to the webpage. I have no idea how as it wasn't working before.

Part 4:

[image]

Added this in base.html

```
{% extends 'Headings/Headings1/base.html' %}
```

[image]

From settings..

```
'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))]  # BASE_DIR / 'templates'
```

Still not found. Yet the webpage is still working.

Comment: Share `TEMPLATES` setting in your settings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your templates folder should be within your app folder home (under about), otherwise Django won't find it.  Check out https://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure.html for the proper file structure.  My guess is the same could be said for the other folders withing your templates folder.  You *can* have a templates folder in your root, but I don't think this is what you will need in your case.

To create a global template, you *can* have a template folder in your root 'testWebsite' directory like you already have.  Then in your settings.py do the following:

```py
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))],
        ...
    },
]
```

What I usually do is create a base.html in each app, then in each of your html pages within the app you can add a line like `{% extends "home/base.html" %}`.  And in each of your base.html files add `{% extends "base.html" %}`

Something like this (I didn't include all the files, just a sample):

```
testWebsite
├── about
│   └── templates
│       └── about
│           ├── base.html
│           └── about.html
├── home
│   └── templates
│       └── home
│           ├── base.html
│           ├── greet.html
│           └── index.html
├── project_long_page
│   └── templates
│       └── project_long_page
│           ├── base.html
│           └── project_long_page.html
├── templates
│   └── base.html
└── testWebsite
    └── settings.py
```

Comment: What if I wanted to use a "Global" template for the header of the website that could be accessed by all?

Comment: I just updated my answer to address your concern.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the changes, ran everything, and then posted an update as Part 2! It still won't work currently.

Comment: The issue is that it is not finding the template `main_header.html` because Django is looking for it in the templates folder of your root project, but you have it within another folder 'Headings1' inside of another folder 'Headings'.  Either put the file directly in the root template folder (suggested), or you can try `{% extends 'Headings/Headings1/base.html' %}`

Comment: P.S. Images of code are never a good idea on stackoverflow.  There are even ways to put folder structure without images, but definitely no images of code :)

Comment: Thank you I removed most photos of code! 

I also updated it and it still won't show it was found yet the website still works.

Why is it bad to do that? Even with folders?

Comment: Often people who answer questions will copy code to either do a search, or to try the code out themselves.  Nothing wrong with images of folder structures as far as I know, that's just my own preference.

Comment: Typo on my part: `{% extends 'Headings/Headings1/main_header.html' %}`.  I always call the layouts.html, base.html.  Sorry.  Please let me know if it works.